# IB_DESIGNABLE and IBInspectable with IOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an IOS application. My application requires IOS 6 or later. I am developing with XCode 6, but I tried to open my project with XCode 5.1.1 then I got error messages this "Unknown type name 'IBInspectable'". So, Do my application work in IOS 6?

Comment: why are you targeting ios 6? Nobody's using that anymore. You should be targeting 7 or 8. Anything you target to 6 will look and feel and possibly work bad in 7 and 8

Answer (score 0):

IBInspectable is only available in Xcode 6 and the iOS 8 SDK. You can't open it with older versions of Xcode but as long as your Deployment Target is set to iOS 6 you should be good. So keep using Xcode 6:)